# Is it possible to split initialize section into different classes?

Tags: java, swing

I have been working on some side project involving `MySQL`, with will use tree different screens: '*menu*, ' *add breed*', '*browse breed*'.

At this point section `initialize` is getting quite large and I would like to split it into 3 different classes.

**Is it possible to initialize for example `JPanel` outside `Window` class?**

```
public class Window  {

    public static void setBreed()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<16;i++) {
            breedLabels[i].setText(breedInfo[i]);
            breedLabels[i].setBounds(600,100+i*30,300, 100);
            breedLabels[i].setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 20));
            viewBreed.add(breedLabels[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void setText()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<16;i++) {
            textLabels[i].setText(text[i]);
            textLabels[i].setBounds(300,100+i*30,300, 100);
            textLabels[i].setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 20));
            viewBreed.add(textLabels[i]);
        }
    }


    public static String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chooseyourpuppy";
    public static String user = "root";
    public static String password = ""; 
    public static String query = "select * from breeds";

    static String [] breedInfo = new String[16];
    static String [] text = new String[16];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Window window = new Window();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });     

        View.connect(URL, user, password, query);
    }

    public Window() {
        initialize();
    }

    private JFrame frame;
    public JPanel addBreed;
    public static JPanel viewBreed;
    public JPanel menu;
    public static JLabel[] textLabels;
    public static JLabel[] breedLabels;

private  void initialize() {

        final int WIDTH = 1280, HEIGHT = 720;
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        frame.setBounds(100, 100, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("MyBREEDS Viewer");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //header
        JPanel red = new JPanel();
        red.setBounds(400, 0, 888, 80);
        frame.getContentPane().add(red);
        red.setBackground(new Color(204, 0, 0));
        red.setLayout(null);

        JPanel darkGrey = new JPanel();
        darkGrey.setBounds(0, 0, 387, 80);
        frame.getContentPane().add(darkGrey);
        darkGrey.setBackground(new Color(51, 51, 51));
        darkGrey.setLayout(null);

        JLabel txtpnChoose = new JLabel();
        txtpnChoose.setForeground(new Color(240, 240, 240));
        txtpnChoose.setBounds(56, 11, 367, 63);
        txtpnChoose.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 46));
        txtpnChoose.setText("Choose your");
        txtpnChoose.setBackground(null);
        darkGrey.add(txtpnChoose);

        JLabel txtpnPuppy = new JLabel();
        txtpnPuppy.setBounds(5, 11, 166, 63);
        txtpnPuppy.setForeground(new Color(240, 240, 240));
        txtpnPuppy.setFont(new Font("Nunito-Bold", Font.BOLD, 46));
        txtpnPuppy.setText("puppy");
        txtpnPuppy.setBackground(null);
        red.add(txtpnPuppy);        

        JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.setBounds(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.getContentPane().add(layeredPane);
        layeredPane.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

        JButton btnMenu = new JButton("Back to menu");
        btnMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                layeredPane.removeAll();
                layeredPane.add(menu);
                layeredPane.repaint();
                layeredPane.revalidate();
            }
        });
        btnMenu.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnMenu.setBackground(new Color(51, 51, 51));
        btnMenu.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 18));
        btnMenu.setBounds(660, 20, 180, 40);
        btnMenu.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnMenu.setFocusPainted(false);
        red.add(btnMenu);

        //menu      
        menu = new JPanel();
        menu.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        layeredPane.add(menu, "name_410359960271086");
        menu.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnBrowse = new JButton("Browse breeds");
        btnBrowse.setBounds(100, 300, 400, 200);
        btnBrowse.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        btnBrowse.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
        btnBrowse.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(new BasicStroke(5.0f)));
        btnBrowse.setBackground(Color.WHITE);       
        btnBrowse.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
        btnBrowse.setVisible(true);
        btnBrowse.setFocusPainted(false);
        btnBrowse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                layeredPane.removeAll();
                layeredPane.add(viewBreed);
                layeredPane.repaint();
                layeredPane.revalidate();
                setText();
                setBreed();
            }
        });

        btnBrowse.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                btnBrowse.setBackground(new Color(237, 237, 237));
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                btnBrowse.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
        });
        menu.add(btnBrowse);

        addBreed = new JPanel();
        layeredPane.add(addBreed, "name_410359942089403");
        addBreed.setVisible(false);
        addBreed.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        addBreed.setLayout(null);   

        //view breed window
        viewBreed = new JPanel();
        layeredPane.add(viewBreed, "name_410359924014670");
        viewBreed.setLayout(null);
        viewBreed.setVisible(false);
        viewBreed.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        ImageIcon previous = new ImageIcon("src/images/previous.png");
        ImageIcon previousHover = new ImageIcon("src/images/previousHover.png");

        JButton prevBreed = new JButton(previous);
        prevBreed.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                prevBreed.setIcon(previousHover);
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                prevBreed.setIcon(previous);
            }
        });
        prevBreed.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                View.changeBreed(false);
            }
        });
        prevBreed.setBounds(30, 300, previous.getIconHeight(), previous.getIconWidth());
        viewBreed.add(prevBreed);
        prevBreed.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
        prevBreed.setOpaque(false);
        prevBreed.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        prevBreed.setBorderPainted(false);
        prevBreed.setFocusPainted(false);

        ImageIcon next = new ImageIcon("src/images/next.png");
        ImageIcon nextHover = new ImageIcon("src/images/nextHover.png");

        JButton nextBreed = new JButton(next);
        nextBreed.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                nextBreed.setIcon(nextHover);
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                nextBreed.setIcon(next);
            }
        });
        nextBreed.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                View.changeBreed(true);
            }
        });
        nextBreed.setBounds(1140, 300, previous.getIconHeight(), previous.getIconWidth());
        viewBreed.add(nextBreed);
        nextBreed.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
        nextBreed.setVisible(true);
        nextBreed.setOpaque(false);
        nextBreed.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        nextBreed.setBorderPainted(false);
        nextBreed.setFocusPainted(false);   

        //add breed window
        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add new breed");
        btnAdd.setBounds(780, 300, 400, 200);
        btnAdd.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        btnAdd.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
        btnAdd.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(new BasicStroke(5.0f)));
        btnAdd.setBackground(Color.WHITE);      
        btnAdd.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
        btnAdd.setFocusPainted(false);
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                layeredPane.removeAll();
                layeredPane.add(addBreed);
                layeredPane.repaint();
                layeredPane.revalidate();
            }
        });

        btnAdd.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                btnAdd.setBackground(new Color(237, 237, 237));
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                btnAdd.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
        });
        menu.add(btnAdd);

        breedLabels = new JLabel[breedInfo.length];

        for(int i=0; i<breedInfo.length; i++) {
            breedLabels[i] = new JLabel(breedInfo[i]);
        }

        textLabels = new JLabel[breedInfo.length];

        for(int i=0; i<breedInfo.length; i++) {
            textLabels[i] = new JLabel(breedInfo[i]);
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to initialize for example `JPanel` outside `Window` class?"

Yes. A different class might contain a method that creates & returns a `JPanel`.

Other tips:

- Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc. using different PLAFs in different locales. As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout. Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).
- Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now. An [embedded-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-resource) must be accessed by URL rather than file. See the [info. page for embedded resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-resource) for how to form the URL.
- `new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 20)` Use defaults or logical fonts (E.G. `Font.SERIF`) unless the font is supplied with your app. as an embedded resource.
- The loop and array of labels that are added to `viewBreed` suggest it should be a `JList` rather than a `JPanel`
- `layeredPane.removeAll();` .. Ugh.. Use a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).
- What is the purpose of the `JLayeredPane`? I expect it's unnecessary purely on the basis that there is so little use for them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and additional feedback.
Thanks to your help I managed to split `initialize`, Now *menu* is in different class.
I have a question to `The loop and array ...` part: this is how `viewBreeds` looks like now - https://i.imgur.com/QeeuoFO.png. 
**Are you sure that I should use JList?**

Comment: If it is displaying two or more data items (e.g. 1) label 2) value) then a `JTable` might be better than a `JList` (though the renderer of a list could be configured to show two pieces of information). Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. Given the `removeAll() ..` part, show each 'view' the user sees ('view' / 'add').